# Non zero curvature and torsion in parametrised curves.

Tags: differential-geometry

A lot of times I find this property but i want to understand what that does it mean graphically, or in other words, what kind of curves have zero curvature or/and zero torsion.

Comment: If the curvature $k(t)=0 $ for allá $t$ then the curse $\alpha(s)$ si a straight line. Nos if torsion $\tau(t)=0$ then the curve is a contain in a plane.

Comment: Have you looked at any basic undergraduate textbooks on curves and surfaces?